# run pm2 from remote shell script

Tags: shell-script, remote

I am trying to write a script which ssh into a bunch of my servers and runs some commands to start my app. One of the commands (pm2) always says pm2: command not found. This is how I'm attempting this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /Path/to/key-pair.pem ubuntu@${ec2ips[i]} 'bash ' << 'STARTAPP'
    cd ~/my-app-folder
    pm2 start ./bin/www --name 'my-app'
    exit
STARTAPP
```

when I ssh in normally, all pm2 commands run fine. If I ssh in and run a script with pm2 in it, it also works as expected. It's only when I try and run it on a remote machine from my machine.

Answer (score 0):

When you run an interactive shell it sets the PATH variable according to your "rc" files (e.g .bash_profile).  When you run that "non-interactive" ssh command then many of these scripts aren't run and so PATH isn't set.

You should include the pathname to `pm2` even if it is the current directory (eg `./pm2` or `/path/to/pm2`) to ensure it is found, or else `export PATH=....` before the call to `pm2`.

Comment: i did 'which pm2' which should get me the path to the executable, correct me if i'm wrong. then i tried doing /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.0.0/bin/pm2 start ./bin/www --name 'my-app' but that is still giving me command not found. did i misunderstand your solution?

Comment: The point is your execution environments are different; does `pm2` use other variables to find things?  Login and run the `env` command and compare that to `ssh server env`; there will be a LOT of differences.  Do any of those variables impact the execution of the command?